# Javascript, run function for 0.5 seconds then stop (Loop)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a node server with raspberry pi gpio modules installed. I'm trying to get my ESC to start and run for 0.5 seconds, then I need it to stop for .5 second, then start again in a loop. however if "start" = 0 (Button off) I need the loop to stop completely and set the servo pulse width to 1000 (Motor Stop)

Here is my code, It kinda works. But doesn't stop

```js
var start = new blynk.VirtualPin(4);
start.on('write', function t(start) {
  if (start == 1) {
    setInterval(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        motor.servoWrite(1920);
      }, 500);
      setInterval(function() {
        motor.servoWrite(1000);
      }, 1000);
    }, 500);
  } else {
    motor.servoWrite(1000);
  }
  motor.servoWrite(1000);
});
```

Could someone show me where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var start = new blynk.VirtualPin(4);
motor.servoWrite(1000);
var interval, timeout;
start.on('write', function t(start) {
  if (start == 1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      motor.servoWrite(1920);
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        motor.servoWrite(1000);
      }, 500);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    motor.servoWrite(1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Store your interval in a variable

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() { [... your code code] },delay);
```

then to stop it by

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Comment: And with the time in milliseconds and the second argument of the function `setInterval`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think `setInterval` might be the wrong thing to use. The `setInterval` is reoccurring. Where you really just want to run something once, wait, then run something else. Try doing it with [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), it waits for x ms then executes something.

```
var id = null;
start.on('write', function t(start) {
    if(start == 1){
        pulse();
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(id);
        motor.servoWrite(1000);
    }   
});

function pulse() {
    servoOn();
    id = setTimeout(function(){
        servoOff();
        id = setTimeout(function(){
            pulse();
        }, 1000);
    }, 500);
}

function servoOn(){
    motor.servoWrite(1920); 
}

function servoOff(){
    motor.servoWrite(1000);
}
```